# using mocker to patch with pytest

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I installed [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) and using a mocker I am trying to function as patch does, but I get "Type Error: Need a valid target to patch.  You supplied 'return a + b'"

```
# test_capitalize.py
import time


def sum(a, b):
    time.sleep(10)
    return a + b

def test_sum(mocker):
    mocker.patch('return a + b');
    assertEqual(sum(2, 3), 9)
```

Comment: You can't patch a string. I assume you want to patch the `sum` function? `mocker.patch(__name__ + '.sum', return_value=9)` or, if you want to patch with a custom function, use `side_effect`: `mocker.patch(__name__ + '.sum', side_effect=lambda a, b: a - b)` etc.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`patch` requires a path to the function being patched. You could do something like this:

```
import pytest


def sum(a, b):
    return a + b


def test_sum1(mocker):
    mocker.patch(__name__ + ".sum", return_value=9)
    assert sum(2, 3) == 9


def test_sum2(mocker):
    def crazy_sum(a, b):
        return b + b

    mocker.patch(__name__ + ".sum", side_effect=crazy_sum)
    assert sum(2, 3) == 6
```

Result:

```
$ pytest -v patch_test.py
============= test session starts ==============
platform cygwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.10.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/xyz/temp, inifile:
plugins: mock-1.10.0, cov-2.6.0
collected 2 items

patch_test.py::test_sum1 PASSED          [ 50%]
patch_test.py::test_sum2 PASSED          [100%]

=========== 2 passed in 0.02 seconds ===========
```

Comment: Is there a way to assert the parameter it was called with?

Comment: @yardstick17 yes: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock